# Android Firebase retrieve data from child node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the data from Firebase child node. But it throws `Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type uk.co.stableweb.geethika.model.DailyVerse` exception.

This is the structure of my Firebase database.

[image: Firebase database structure.]

Here is the code. I'm using Android Firebase new [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data).

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("daily_verse");
mRef.keepSynced(true);

ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d("Child Event,Verse", dataSnapshot.getKey());

        dailyVerse = dataSnapshot.getValue(DailyVerse.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d("Child Event,Verse", "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

        dailyVerse = dataSnapshot.getValue(DailyVerse.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w("Firebase", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to load verse",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

mRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

And Model class.

```
public class DailyVerse {

    private String verse_title;
    private String verse_content;

    public String getVerseTitle() {
        return verse_title;
    }

    public void setVerseTitle(String verse_title) {
        this.verse_title = verse_title;
    }

    public String getVerseContent() {
        return verse_content;
    }

    public void setVerseContent(String verse_content) {
        this.verse_content = verse_content;
    }
}
```

And the LogCat.

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type uk.co.stableweb.geethika.model.DailyVerse
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalq.zzd(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalq.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalq.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
  at uk.co.stableweb.geethika.VerseActivityFragment$1.onChildAdded(VerseActivityFragment.java:63)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahh.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh.zzctc(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajk$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

But if I change the database reference as follows. And get the dataSnapshot value, it grabs the data.

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("daily_verse");

testVal = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
Log.d("TEST", testVal);

V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 278033062
D/Child Event,Verse added: verse_content
D/TEST: විශ්වාසකමේ මාර්ගය තෝරා ගතිමි. ඔබගේ විනිශ්චයන් මා ඉදිරියෙහි තබා ගතිමි.
D/Child Event,Verse added: verse_title
D/TEST: ගීතාවලිය 119:30
```

I think it is possible to get those values using HashMap. But there was a comment saying it is no longer recommended.

Comment: type is mismatched here, check the type you declare on firebase database for verse_content

Comment: I don't understand, isn't Android database store values as json, so type is string right?

Answer (score 5):

Pay careful attention to the names of your properties in the JSON and your fields/getters in the Java code. If they don't match, the Firebase client won't be able to match the values between them.

Your JSON has `verse_title` and `verse_content`, so your Java class must be *either*:

```
public class DailyVerse {
    public String verse_title;
    public String verse_content;    
}
```

*or*:

```
public class DailyVerse {

    private String verse_title;
    private String verse_content;

    public String getVerse_title() {
        return verse_title;
    }

    public void setVerse_title(String verse_title) {
        this.verse_title = verse_title;
    }

    public String getVerse_content() {
        return verse_content;
    }

    public void setVerse_content(String verse_content) {
        this.verse_content = verse_content;
    }
}
```

Since Firebase Android SDK 9.2, you can also annotate your Java code to map to the correct JSON properties. So a third way to get the correct mapping is:

```
public class DailyVerse {

    private String verse_title;
    private String verse_content;

    @PropertyName("verse_title")
    public String getVerseTitle() {
        return verse_title;
    }

    public void setVerseTitle(String verse_title) {
        this.verse_title = verse_title;
    }

    @PropertyName("verse_content")
    public String getVerseContent() {
        return verse_content;
    }

    public void setVerseContent(String verse_content) {
        this.verse_content = verse_content;
    }
}
```

I haven't tried that latest variant though, so let me know if there are typos on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

By this method

```
mRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

you subscribe for

```
.child("daily_verse");
```

children. daily_verse has two children: verse_content and verse_title. The type of these children is String. So, you get two String datasnapshot in the onChildAdd listener.

**Update:**
Try something like this:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mRef.keepSynced(true);

ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d("Child Event,Verse", dataSnapshot.getKey());
        if ("daily_verse".equal(dataSnapshot().getKey){
            dailyVerse = dataSnapshot.getValue(DailyVerse.class);
            Log.d("TEST","Object: "+dailyVerse);
            if (dailyVerse!=null){
               Log.d("TEST","values: "+dailyVerse.verse_title+", "+dailyVerse.verse_content);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d("Child Event,Verse", "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        if ("daily_verse".equal(dataSnapshot().getKey){
          dailyVerse = dataSnapshot.getValue(DailyVerse.class);
          Log.d("TEST","Changed object: "+dailyVerse);
          if (dailyVerse!=null){
             Log.d("TEST","Changed values: "+dailyVerse.verse_title+", "+dailyVerse.verse_content);
          }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w("Firebase", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to load verse",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

mRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

You should subscribe to events from parent object and check the key at events listener.

Comment: Yes, but it returns string.If the returned values is object, why can't I use following statement. dailyVerse = dataSnapshot.getValue(DailyVerse.class);

Comment: Still, not working. I get log as D/TEST: DataSnapshot { key = daily_verse, value = {verse_title=ගීතාවලිය 119:30, verse_content=විශ්වාසකමේ මාර්ගය තෝරා ගතිමි. ඔබගේ විනිශ්චයන් මා ඉදිරියෙහි තබා ගතිමි.} }
D/Child Event,Verse added: geethika

Comment: Does it throw an exception?

Comment: No. But model is null. If I try to get model value, it shows and exception, NullPointerException. Which means dataSnapshot is not passing any values to the model class.

Comment: @Isuru I updated the code again. Please, send me output. Also, would be fine if you send me a link to your code. I will check it.

Comment: Isuru and @Alexey have you solved this issue?Can you help me If you have found solution? here the link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268811/firebase-database-data-retrieving-java

Answer (score 1):

```
DataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

DataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String acctname = (String)dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();
                String acctmail = (String)dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a firebase model class, You have to include an empty constructor for firebase to work with.

Try adding it as

```
public class DailyVerse {
    public DailyVerse(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<EventsResponse> usersEventsList = new ArrayList<>();
    dummyIdsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<DataSnapshot> eventsIterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
    while (eventsIterator.hasNext()) {
        DataSnapshot eventsSnapShot = eventsIterator.next();
        EventsResponse eventsResponse = new EventsResponse();
        eventsResponse.setEventName(eventsSnapShot.getKey());
        Iterator<DataSnapshot> eventChildIterator = eventsSnapShot.getChildren().iterator();
        while (eventChildIterator.hasNext()) {
            DataSnapshot eventchildSnapshot = eventChildIterator.next();
            if (eventchildSnapshot.getKey().equals("is_recursive")) {
                eventsResponse.setRecursive((Boolean) eventchildSnapshot.getValue());
            } else if (eventchildSnapshot.getKey().equals("is_notif")) {
                eventsResponse.setNotif((Boolean) eventchildSnapshot.getValue());
            } else if (eventchildSnapshot.getKey().equals("is_editable")) {
                eventsResponse.setEditable((Boolean) eventchildSnapshot.getValue());
            } else if (eventchildSnapshot.getKey().equals("is_visible")) {
                eventsResponse.setVisible((Boolean) eventchildSnapshot.getValue());
            } else if (eventchildSnapshot.getKey().equals("name")) {
                eventsResponse.setName(eventchildSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            } else if (eventchildSnapshot.getKey().equals("date")) {
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> eventChildDateIterator = eventchildSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while (eventChildDateIterator.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot eventchildDateSnapshot = eventChildDateIterator.next();
                    if (eventchildDateSnapshot.getKey().equals("day")) {
                        eventsResponse.setDay(eventchildDateSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    } else if (eventchildDateSnapshot.getKey().equals("month")) {
                        eventsResponse.setMonth(eventchildDateSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    } else if (eventchildDateSnapshot.getKey().equals("year")) {
                        eventsResponse.setYear(eventchildDateSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                eventsResponse.setNotif(true);
                eventsResponse.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
```

if you are not able to fetch data,then you can fetch the data in that format.