# Firebase database data retrieving -Java

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my DB structure:

[image]

Code which I used for data reading:

```
user="hrcj7";
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
                                        Query phoneQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild(user);
                                        phoneQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                                                User dinosaur = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                                System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey() + " was " + dinosaur.getEmail() + " meters tall.");
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                                            }


                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                Log.e("App", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                                            }
                                        });
```

This is the dataSnapsshot value after retrieving:

```
DataSnapshot {
    key = hrcj7,
    value = {
        -Kh2-jOeGXCOr-VE3uD5={
            username=hrcj7,
            email=rperera723@gmail.com,
            imageurl=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/freelancer-33195.appspot.com/o/Blog_Images%2Fcropped933315999.jpg?alt=media&token=7890f05f-87db-4a9d-9534-02da00225470
        }
    }
}
```

This is the model class:

```
public class User {


            public String email;
            public String imageurl;
            public String username;

            public User(String email,String imageurl,String username) {

                this.email = email;
                this.imageurl=imageurl;
                this.username=username;
            }

            public String getEmail() {
                return email;
            }

            public void setEmail(String email) {
                this.email = email;
            }

            public String getImageurl() {
                return imageurl;
            }

            public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
                this.imageurl = imageurl;
            }

            public String getUsername() {
                return username;
            }

            public void setUsername(String username) {
                this.username = username;
            }
     public User() {
            // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
        }

        }
```

My problem is that `dinosaur.getEmail()` get null after retrieving the value. What can be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is a dinosaur "email meters tall"?

Comment: I'm getting null value for dinosaur.getEmail()

Comment: In `mDatabase.orderByChild(user);` we have no way to know what `mDatabase` and `users` are. Please make sure the code is complete enough to reproduce the problem, as these two are quite critical. It helps to: 1) use hard-coded values where possible, 2) start from `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()`.

Comment: I updated my code mate.Is there any problem with my model class?Because data was retrieved by the code.But I code not set those values to dinosaur object.I attached Json value also.

Comment: You've expanded it to include *more* code, instead of the minimum I asked for. That requires us to digest significant *and* doesn't rule out simple typos in your UI (or in your JSON, such as the extra space after the email address). Please read about [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you Frank van Puffelen for the valuable advice.I hope that now I have provided sufficient information about the issue and I fixed email address extra space issue.

Comment: I used this solution also but It was not working. ref-http://stackoverflow.com/a/41192297/4058157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found the solution .

**In line:**

```
User dinosaur = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

**should be replaced as following:**

```
String key = mDatabase.child("User").child(user).push().getKey();
User dinosaur = dataSnapshot.child(key).getValue(User.class);
```